# "Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file" when trying to open connection with ADODB to query .csv files

Tags: excel, vba, oledb, adodb

I'm trying to run SQL queries on .csv files using VBA, however when I attempt to open a connection using any directory on my local computer, I get an error

> "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '[directory name]'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data."

I don't have administrator privileges, but I am able to open the csv files and edit them normally. Do I need administrator privileges to open this connection? Here is my code so far:

```
Sub generateStudentOfficeVisitsReport()

Dim currentDir As String

currentDir = VBAProject.ThisWorkbook.Path + "\"
Debug.Print ("Current Dir: '" + currentDir + "'")

Dim filter As String

filter = "SHARRSDiagnostic*.csv"

Dim currentFile As String
currentFile = Dir(currentDir & filter)
Dim cN As ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Set cN = New ADODB.Connection
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

cN.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & currentDir & """;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';")

RS.ActiveConnection = cN

Do Until currentFile = ""
    Debug.Print (currentFile)

    RS.Source = "select * from " & currentFile '
    
    'TODO
    
    currentFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

I tried adding single/double quotes around all my parameters in the db connection string because I saw that sometimes solved issues for others, but that didn't work for me. I also tried adding parameters like "Trusted_connection=yes;" and "Integrated Security=SSPI" to see if it would satisfy some security requirement, but the former gave an error "Could not find installable ISAM", and the latter "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors".

Comment: Does `RS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & currentFile, cN` do any better?  And you should not need the `"""` in the connection string.

Comment: @TimRoberts No unfortunately, the error is happening on the cN.Open call so the connection is not getting opened

Comment: Did you close your files before? I mean, Excel should be closed.  CTRL ALT DEL and kill all Excel processes.

Comment: @b126 I need to have excel open to run the script, but I closed all other windows

Comment: So what does Access makes here? Sorry I don’t undersand. I thought you were exporting from Access to Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string should look like

```
cn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
    & currentDir & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'")
```

as you want to connect to a text file.

Further [Reading](https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/)